# Windows 10 - modify drivers from CMD

Tags: windows-10, boot, drivers, bios

Long story short, I screwed up.

Anyway, as per this website: https://samnicholls.net/2016/01/14/how-to-switch-sata-raid-to-ahci-windows-10-xps-13/, I updated a driver in Windows 10 so that I could boot with AHCI mode instead of RAID.  It didn't work.  In fact, now Windows won't boot in either mode.  I can access CMD and regedit from the recovery screen, so I was wondering if through a combination of basic CMD commands, regedit, and file manipulation (I can access the windows filesystem from a linux installation, so at least I haven't lost my files), I could switch the driver back to its original configuration.

In other words: The tutorial showed me how to change it from **Intel SATA RAID Controller** to **Microsoft Storage Spaces Controller**.  I need to change it *back*.  My tools are:

- Complete access to the filesystem from a Linux USB
- CMD (in the advanced startup tools)
- regedit

I'm on a Dell XPS 15 9560, Windows 10 (the corrupt OS) and Kali Linux (the working OS).

Comment: UEFI or Legacy?

Comment: @MichaelBay UEFI

Comment: Have you tried doing a system restore to a point in time before the unwanted change was made?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator - That did it.  I did a system restore to a miraculous point that was created yesterday when I updated the JetBrains suite.  After that it booted (mostly) fine.  It got me in so I could fix the driver issue and restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This sounds like a job for System Restore.** SR allows you to revert changes made to the Registry, and all critical system files, including drivers.

Because Windows makes restore points on a regular basis you should hopefully have a recent restore point that was made before the unwanted change to your storage driver.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to the command prompt you can try the following. These are inbuilt tools in Windows 10 to restore drivers if certain drivers get corrupted. Some of these commands will connect to Microsoft and download drivers so you may want to make sure you are connected to Wifi by using `ping microsoft.com`:

#### In the Command Prompt type the following command and press Enter. This will check the health of your Windows partition:

```
sfc /scannow
```

#### Use the DISM command with the /CheckHealth switch

This is to verify whether any corruption has been detected. This command can only be used to see if corruption exists, but it doesn't perform any repairs.

Type the following command and press Enter:

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
```

#### Using DISM with the ScanHealth option

Use the DISM command with the /ScanHealth switch to scan the Windows image for any corruption. Unlike the /CheckHealth, the /ScanHealth switch can take up to 10 minutes to complete the process.

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth
```

#### Using DISM with the RestoreHearlh option

Use the DISM command with the /RestoreHealth switch to scan the Windows image for any corruption and to perform a repair automatically. Unlike the /ScanHealth switch, the /RestoreHealth switch can take up to 20 minutes to complete the process.

Type the following command and press Enter:

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

When you run the command mentioned above, DISM will try to use Windows Update to replace the damaged files. However, if the problem has also extended to the Windows Update components, then you'll need to specify a source containing the known good files to repair the image.

#### Lastly download the ISO

from [Microsoft] (!https://www.windowscentral.com/e?link=http%3A%2F%2Fclkde.tradedoubler.com%2Fclick%3Fp%3D259740%26a%3D2542549%26g%3D0%26epi%3DUUwpUdUnU38864YYw%26url%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.microsoft.com%252Fen-us%252Fsoftware-download%252Fwindows10&token=3BvfZPM6 OR http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/F/9/CF9862F9-3D22-4811-99E7-68CE3327DAE6/MediaCreationTool.exe)

Comment: I don't have access to the internet while using cmd

Comment: @vcapra1 You can use the Windows installation media to boot from and repair Windows (no internet connection required). This will most likely put Windows as the first boot priority (boot Windows directly) but after assuring Windows is working fine, do: 1. Disable Fast Startup and shutdown. 2. Go to UEFI settings and select Kali as the first priority again and boot Kali. 3. Run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: yes.. I would do what @MichaelBay suggested.. It is not mandatory that you need to have internet access for the above to work. Also, if you dont have the Windows Installation media, you can download the ISO and burn it to a disc from Linux. Then a) try to repair it directly by booting from the CD or b) run the above commands again while the DVD/CD in the drive. A long while back when I had such issues, Windows was smart enough to grab drivers from the DVD drive, if there was no internet access.